# Different formats for JGROUPS configuration file

Tags: jgroups

Per the JGroups documentation, they show configuration as the following

[image]

In actual configuration files, I see the following :

[image]

Questions

1 - How is this command

```
initial_hosts="${jgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts:server1[9000],server2[9001]}"
```

different from

```
initial_hosts="server1[9000],server2[9001]"
```

Or are they the same?

2 - Where are the various parameters defined and are their any advantages to using them?

```
jgroups.tcpping.initial_hosts
jgroups.tcpping.return_entire_cache
jgroups.tcp.port_range
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)